# Java Sql Database Parameter Index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Hello I am trying to insert into a database and I am getting the error:

```
 SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).
```

The code causing this is:

```
 PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Members VALUES  ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?'','?','?','?','?','?'");
        st.setString(1, username);
        st.setString(2, id);
        st.setString(3, firstName);
        st.setString(4, lastName);
        st.setString(5, address);
        st.setString(6, phone);
        st.setString(7, email);
        st.setInt(8, age);
        st.setString(9, String.valueOf(sex));
        st.setDouble(10, height);
        st.setInt(11, kgs);
        st.setDouble(12, stone);
        st.setInt(13, targetWeightKgs);
        st.setDouble(14, bmi);
        st.setString(15, medicalHistory);
        st.setString(16, extraHistory);
        st.setBoolean(17, smoker);
        st.setBoolean(18, usernameCompleted);
        st.setString(19, myNotes);
        st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you show the database table?

Answer (score 1):

You should not quote your `?` placeholders, even if they represent string data.  Quoted question marks will be intrepreted as literal `'?'` strings.  It's probably interpreted as 5 parameters because your 6th to last parameter has two `'` characters, so your last 5 `?`s are interpreted as outside of single-quotes.

Try

```
connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Members VALUES
   (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

**UPDATE**

There was a closing ")" missing in the insert statement, that I have now added.

Comment: Using prepareStatement is great but surely there must exist a better way to create a more complex prepareStatement such as this one. I mean using 15x '?' is just not feasible...

Comment: @i-bob Your comment doesn't make much sense.  Why create a more complex `PreparedStatement` than this one?  There is nothing in the question to suggest that anything more complex is necessary, or that this needs to be executed 15 times, although a `PreparedStatement` would be the way to go anyway.

Comment: I mean, surely this is a valid answer to the question, I just asked how to do it perhaps in some better way and if somebody know how then he can share it with us... I mean using things like DAOs etc...

Comment: @i-bob If you have a specific question about your code and a better way to use a DAO with a `PreparedStatement`, then you can always ask it as another question.

Comment: It was not in any way a criticism of your solution, just a simple curiosity about other options... :)

Comment: @i-bob I have some prepared statements in live code that have 50+ `?` placeholders.

Comment: There was a missing ")" in the insert statement.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `'` surrounding the `?`'s.

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Members VALUES  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");
```

`BUT` the real problem here is you double single quoted one of the `?` to look like :`'?'',`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your sample code at line

`preparedStatement` if you have done the same mistake in your original code then it will not work!

Check out the question marks and `'` you don't need `'`

Answer (score 0):

replace '?' by ?

```
INSERT INTO Members VALUES  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```